# IBM bluemix Cloud Foundry php lack https support?

Tags: php, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

When using below function on cf, if the $url starts with "https:", the method always returns false:

```
file_get_contents($url);
```

If I change the $url from "https" to "http", then it works. Is this the problem of CF or is there anyway I can use "https" to grab content from other site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable openssl support adding related extension in .bp-config/options.json
For example

```
{
   "PHP_EXTENSIONS": [" openssl"]
}
```

Comment: You can find it in your local copy of the apps, at the same level of manifest.yml. if not present you can create .bp-config directory and options.json inside.

Comment: So how could I know that I can add those file in the project??I follow your instruct and create the folder then it works.Is there any offcial documentation I'm missing???

Comment: If you followed my instructions correctly you have now a .bp-config directory in the root of your application folder and a options.json inside. Pushing the app as usual it will be used by cf to customize your runtime. For further documentation look for cf customization using .bp-config/options.json

Comment: You can also specify PHP extensions that your application requires through Composer.  For example, add `"ext-openssl": "*"` to the `require` block of your `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

To get contents from  protocal https, you need to have openssl extenstion enabled from php.ini file.Did you check that is enabled or not.